# Seminal discharge during bowel movement. Is ghusl required?

Tags: ghusl

I have this personal issue. Whenever I have a bowel movement, semen is discharged. I'm pretty sure it's semen. I have read that ghusl is required if there is discharge due to desire. What is the definition of desire and when does one know whether something came out out of desire or not. I'm in doubt concerning this, so what used to happen is that I would worry so much about having any sexual thoughts during bowel movement because if semen was dischared at the same time or a little after, then I'd need ghusl. I became so worried about having sexual thoughts that I started having sexual thoughts during bowel movements and this made me stressed and angry, because I thought I would need ghusl. I started ignoring these doubts because it became too much on me and it didn't make sense logically. So I prayed without doing ghusl. Do I need ghusl eveytime? What if something sexual crosses my mind and at the same time something is discharged? Does this require ghusl? Even if the discharge was likely only because of straining during bowel movement? I would like evidence from hadith and Quran, something I myself could double check. I am going to see a urologist in a few months.